# making use of libcurl progress data

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa, libcurl

In Xcode set up a stack of curl_easy_setopt-functions for uploading a file to a server/API, and (after a lot of trial and error) it all works like a charm. After going through several other Q&As i also managed to set up an easy CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION that looks like this:

```
static int my_progress_func(void *p,
                        double t,
                        double d,
                        double ultotal,
                        double ulnow)
{
printf("(%g %%)\n", ulnow*100.0/ultotal);
// globalProgressNumber = ulnow*100.0/ultotal;
return 0;
}
```

As the upload progresses "0%.. 16%.. 58%.. 100%" is output to the console; splendid.
What i'm not able to do is to actually USE this data (globalProgressNumber) eg. for my NSProgressIndicator; CURL kind of hijacks my App and doesn't allow any other input/output until the progress is complete.

I tried updating IBOutlets from my_progress_func (eg. [_myLabel setStringValue:globalProgressNumber];) but the static int function doesn't allow that.
Neither is [self] allowed, so posting to NSNotificationCenter isn't possible:
    `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:@"Progressing"
    object:self];`

My curl function runs from my main class/ window (NSPanel).

Any good advice on how to achieve a realtime/ updating element on my .xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *CURL [...] doesn't allow any other input/output until the progress is complete.*

Are you calling `curl_easy_perform` from the main thread? If yes, you should not do that since this function is synchronous, i.e it blocks until the transfer finishes.

In other words long running tasks (e.g with network I/O) must run on a separate thread, while UI code (e.g. updating the text of a label) must run on the main thread.

> *how to achieve a realtime/updating element*

You should definitely take care to perform the curl transfer in a separate thread.

This could be easily achieved by wrapping this into an `NSOperation` with a custom protocol to notify a delegate of the progress (e.g your view controller):

- push your operation into an `NSOperationQueue`,
- the operation queue will take care to detach the transfer and run it into an another thread,
- on the operation side, you should still use the progress function and set the operation object as the opaque object via the `CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA` curl option. By doing so, each time the progress function is called you can retrieve the operation object by casting the `void *clientp` opaque pointer. Then notify the delegate of the current progress **in the main thread** (e.g with `performSelectorOnMainThread`) to make sure you can perform UI updates such as refreshing your `NSProgressIndicator`.

As an alternative to an `NSOperation` you can also use [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) (GCD) and blocks. If possible, I greatly recommend you to work with [BBHTTP](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBHTTP) which is a libcurl client for iOS 5+ and OSX 10.7+ (BBHTTP uses GCD and blocks).

FYI: here's an [example from BBHTTP](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBHTTP/blob/17189609949da7ab6464b0d5a6df4d8e5bfd38cf/Example/iOS%20Sample%20app/Classes/AppDelegate.m#L85-L103) that illustrates how to easily perform a file upload with an upload progress block - this is for iOS but should be directly reusable for OS X.

Comment: Thank you; NSOperationQueue really did the trick! With that implemented all i needed to do was to call a performSelectorOnMainThread-function to access my progress data. The result: http://ppsht.com - BBHTTP definitely seems like the best option for any future project!